# Java JSON parse error

Tags: java, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть 2 таблицы в БД с соотношением @ManyToMany с соединением через третью таблицу

Первая сущность OrderRequest

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity(name = "hm_order_request")
public class OrderRequest extends BaseModel {

    @Column(name = "type_of_work_note")
    private String typeOfWorkNote;

    @Column(name = "order_address")
    private String orderAddress;

    @Column(name = "order_note")
    private String orderNote;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "updated")
    private LocalDateTime updated;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "reach_goal_id")
    private ReachGoal reachGoal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_request_to_type_of_work",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_request_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_of_work_id")
    )
    private List<TypeOfWork> typeOfWorkList;
}
```

Вторая сущность TypeOfWork

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity(name = "type_of_work")
public class TypeOfWork {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type_of_work_name")
    private String typeOfWork;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable (
            name = "order_request_to_type_of_work",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "type_of_work_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_request_id")
    )
    private List<OrderRequest> orderRequestList;
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "client":{
        
                            "name":"Client name",
                            "surname":"surname",
                            "patronymic":"patronymic",
                            "citizenship":"RUSSIA",
                            "phone":"phone",
                            "workPhone":"workPhone",
                            "note":"note",
                            "sex":"MALE",
                            "age":"25-35"   
    },

    "typeOfWork":["Сантехник","Сборка мебели"],

    "orderRequest":{
                            "typeOfWorkNote":"typeOfWorkNote",
                            "orderAddress":"orderAddress",
                            "orderNote":"orderNote"
        
    }   

}
```

JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.analytics77j.analytics77j.models.TypeOfWork (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Сантехник');

Я не могу самостоятельно справится ( В БД в таблице type_of_work "Сантехник" и "Сборка мебели есть"

Comment: А модельку TypeOfWork можете показать?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я обновил, выложил полный код

Comment: Вообще typeofwork должен быть массив объектов, а тут получается массив стрингов.   И orderRequest должен быть вложен в typeOfWork. typeOfWorklist:[{typeofwork:'', orderRequest:{}},{},{}] с телефона не удобно, но примерно так должно быть, если не получится, то как буду за компом ещё посмотрю

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы мне дали ответ

Comment: Warheart - вы очень хорошо объясняете, а, случайно, преподаванием не занимаетесь? Я бы взял у вас пару уроков, естественно оплачиваемых

Comment: Нет:) это не ко мне)))

Comment: Оформлю тогда ответом:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeofwork должен быть массив объектов, а тут получается массив стрингов. И orderRequest должен быть вложен в typeOfWork. `typeOfWorklist:[{typeofwork:'', orderRequest:{}},{},{}]`